# Calculating average time difference by group using dplyr

Tags: r, date, dplyr

Say I have the following data frame representing the dates users registered an application in various companies:

```
df <- data.frame(user = c("Tia", "Sam", "Matt", "Brandy", "Joe", "Nariko"),
                 company = c("Intel", "Intel", "Nvidia", "Nvidia", "Nvidia", "Google"),
                 registrationDate = as.Date(c("2015-01-04", "2015-01-04", "2015-01-19", 
                                              "2015-01-20", "2015-01-20", "2015-01-25")),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

How do I create a vector that would give me the average time difference between users at each company to register the application?

I am having some trouble getting simple summary statistics by company over the date variable. For example, when I try to find the maximum registration date for each company using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(company) %>%
  mutate(maxDate = max(registrationDate))
```

I get the maximum date over the entire registrationDate vector replicated for each row in the data frame. It is as though the max() function ignores dplyr's piping.

Comment: Can you show the expected output as it is not clear from your description and code.  Is it `df %>% group_by(company) %>% mutate(AvgTime = mean(diff(registrationDate)))`

Comment: Sorry, that was unclear. I would like the maximum time difference divided by the number of users per company. Something like (difftime(max(df$registrationDate), min(df$registrationDate)))/num_users

Comment: @akrun For some reason the result of your mutate function calculates avgTime to be 4.2 for every company. But, say if we were to first filter the df using `df2 <- filter(df, company == "Nvidia")` and then run your code again on df2, we would find that the avgTime is now 0.5

Comment: maybe `df %>% group_by(company) %>% mutate(new = max(diff(registrationDate))/ length(unique(user)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df %>% group_by(company) %>% 
  mutate(AvgTime = (max(registrationDate)-min(registrationDate))/length(company))

    user company registrationDate        AvgTime
1    Tia   Intel       2015-01-04 0.0000000 days
2    Sam   Intel       2015-01-04 0.0000000 days
3   Matt  Nvidia       2015-01-19 0.3333333 days
4 Brandy  Nvidia       2015-01-20 0.3333333 days
5    Joe  Nvidia       2015-01-20 0.3333333 days
6 Nariko  Google       2015-01-25 0.0000000 days
```

Comment: That is what I was looking for! However, running your line on my machine I get `AvgTime = 3.5` for every row?

Comment: Resolved it. I had to delete and reinstall dplyr on my mac. Not sure what was going on there.

Answer (score 1):

Another one, using `summarize` instead of `mutate`:

```
df2 = df %>% 
  group_by(company) %>%
  summarize(minDate = min(registrationDate), maxDate = max(registrationDate), num_users = n())

> df2
Source: local data frame [3 x 4]

   company    minDate    maxDate num_users
     (chr)     (date)     (date)     (int)
 1  Google 2015-01-25 2015-01-25         1
 2   Intel 2015-01-04 2015-01-04         2
 3  Nvidia 2015-01-19 2015-01-20         3

df2$result = difftime(df2$maxDate, df2$minDate, units = "days")/df2$num_users

> df2
Source: local data frame [3 x 5]

  company    minDate    maxDate num_users     result
    (chr)     (date)     (date)     (int)     (dfft)
1  Google 2015-01-25 2015-01-25         1     0 days
2   Intel 2015-01-04 2015-01-04         2     0 days
3  Nvidia 2015-01-19 2015-01-20         3 0.3333333 days
```